# Can we introduce first person usage while editing?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, title

I've had this question bugging my mind, always when I'm editing posts on SO. Sometimes the question itself requires some edits. In these times, I'm really not sure if I should edit and add some information regarding the question in first person.
For e.g.:

Question:

> How to view all items of ComboBox.

My *edit*:

> I want to view all items of a ComboBox in a winforms application, using C#.

Is the use of 'I' in my edit justifiable?

Comment: Is this the title or body? Because if it's the title, then it's fine as it is. If it's the body, using "I" is fine, and "in a winforms application, using C#" is less problematic to have in the body (provided the question ticks all the other boxes).

Comment: In case you are talking about the title, I wouldn't get rid of the "question". I would go for: "How can I view all items of a ComboBox in a WinForms application?" I wouldn't put "using C#" into the title because C# goes to the tag line.

Comment: Yeah, at most I would mention WinForms but C# isn't really necessary - a System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox is a System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox however you spin it.

Comment: Both title and body. For some reason it felt wrong to 'put your feet in the shoes which belong to someone else'.

Comment: Yes, of course you can introduce first person. **Don't overthink this.** Titles should be short and punchy; question bodies should be descriptive and grammatically correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference between *"How to view all items of ComboBox"* and *"I want to view all items of a ComboBox in a winforms application, using C#"* is that you added `winforms application`, and `C#`.

Winforms and C# must be tags, not in the title. Your title is uselessly more complex.
<sup>[Do not use tags in question titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)</sup>

From my point of view, using the first person in a title is not a problem in itself, unnecessarily stretching titles is one

If you absolutely want to put "I" in the title, I think *"How can I view all items of a ComboBox?"* may be better.

---

I allow myself to quote [*@CodyGray* from comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352017/can-we-introduce-first-person-usage-while-editing/352038#comment491210_352017):

> Titles should be short and punchy; question bodies should be
>   descriptive and grammatically correct.

Comment: Just because a word exists as a tag, doesn't mean there's a prohibition on it also being in a title. The rule is to not _force_tags into the title. "Reverse an array" is not specific enough. "Reverse a Ruby array" is substantially better: it tells me that I'm not going to find help for the code I am writing in C.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Indeed, but so would the ruby tag that should be on the question. Still, having the information in the title makes it so much easier to scan listings of questions / google search results.

Comment: Tags in general (of course the major tag is prepended to the page title) don't help until you're on the site, and we all know how well the on-site search works.

Answer (score -3):

I wouldn't recommend the use of first person for two reasons:

Firstly a 'How' question is more search engine optimized and helps SO posts appear higher in a search engine result

The word 'How' captures the attention of a SO user stating that this is a request for a procedure to do something and hence conveys a better meaning.